# pandas plot hide x axis when subplots and secondary y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a problem with pandas and couldn't figure out why. I want to create a figure with two subplots and plotting all the subplots x axis labels. Here is the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value A': np.random.random(10), 'value B': np.random.random(10)*np.random.random_sample()*10.,
    'value C': np.concatenate((np.tile(1, 5),np.tile(2,5)))}, index=pd.date_range('2015-03-02', periods=10, freq='D'))
print(df)
```

here is the plotting code:

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12,8), tight_layout=True)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
df[['value A', 'value B']][df['value C'] == 1].plot(ax=ax1, grid=True, secondary_y='value B')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
df[['value A', 'value B']][df['value C'] == 2].plot(ax=ax2, grid=True, secondary_y='value B')

plt.show()
```

this code will show **no x axis labels on the top plot**. Instead this will show them:

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12,8), tight_layout=True)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
df[['value A', 'value B']][df['value C'] == 1].plot(ax=ax1, grid=True)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
df[['value A', 'value B']][df['value C'] == 2].plot(ax=ax2, grid=True, secondary_y='value B')

plt.show()
```

or this:

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12,8), tight_layout=True)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
df[['value A', 'value B']][df['value C'] == 1].plot(ax=ax1, grid=True, secondary_y='value B')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

plt.show()
```

Would help me figure out why please?
I also tried to set the ticks manually in the top plot using

```
gca().get_xaxis().set_xticks()
gca().get_xaxis().set_xticklabels()
```

pandas v 0.18

matplotlib v 1.5.1

but it isn't working.
Thanks a lot!
Serg